Uploading Photos to Server in C# MAUI: Best Practices?
I'm working on a C# MAUI application that needs to capture photos from the device's camera and upload them to a server. I'm encountering two specific issues:
Capturing Photos
When I call CapturePhotoAsync() from the Microsoft.Maui.Media namespace, the application crashes with the following error:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I've added the necessary camera permissions to the Android manifest:
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

How can I resolve this error and successfully capture photos in my MAUI application?
Uploading Photos to a Server
After capturing the photo, I want to upload it to a server using an HTTP POST request. I'm using the HttpClient class to make the request, but I'm unsure about the best way to handle the file upload. Should I convert the photo to a byte array and include it in the request body? Or is there a better approach?
Here's a snippet of my current code for uploading the photo:
var photo = await CapturePhotoAsync();
var byteArray = photo.ToByteArray();

var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://example.com/upload", content);`

Is this the correct way to upload the photo, or am I missing something?

have you read the extensive comments on Android permissions for that library in the docs?

Is your question about making a photo (that seems to be the problem) or uploading the photo (as you say)? Decide for one.

You can use MediaPicker for functionality  and add  the  permissions for it, for more information ,please refer to MediaPicker.

I've added the following permissions and it works great.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />


Other than that, I use MediaPicker for functionality .For more information ,please refer to the  MediaPicker.Here is my code.
private async void CaptureAndUploadPhotoAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
   {
       //capturing photos
       FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();
       if (photo != null)
       {

           var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
           //Read the contents of the file and convert it to an array of bytes
           var byteArray = await FileToByteArrayAsync(photo);
           var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
           content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
           var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://example.com/upload", content);
       }

   }
}

public async Task<byte[]> FileToByteArrayAsync(FileResult file)
{

   using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
   {
       using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
       {


           await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
           return memoryStream.ToArray();

       }


   }

}

